# Contractor didn't fix the problem and made superfluous work

Tags: contractor, dispute

I had a roof leak; the first roofer inspecting the problem replaced some chipped tiles and also replaced a missing dry verge (which was not related to the leak problem).
However, the leak was still there, and had become an emergency, so I e-mailed the roofer with pictures documenting the problem and asked for further action.
No answer, so I hired another roofer to re-tile the roof from scratch, and the leak was solved.

After two weeks or so the first roofer replied, I told him the problem was fixed despite his unresponsiveness.
He charged me for his part (fair enough), but he also included the material and labor for replacing the dry verge, which wasn't part of the problem, and which was made completely useless since in the end everything, including the dry verges, was replaced.
Additionally, I never asked him to fix the missing dry verge (exactly because I wasn't sure whether the old tiling would have been there after fixing the main problem).

It is not a big amount of money (under 150 gbp); however, this situation bothers me: should I try to argue with the roofer or that's not worth the hassle?

Comment: I'm not sure whether anyone other that you can determine whether it's worth the hassle to you.  For some people, it would be worth it to spend hundreds of hours and go to court over the principle.  For others, a simple monetary calculation would be "eh, better to spend a few extra hours working than arguing with a roofer" which would depend obviously on what you value your time at.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about personal finance.

Comment: @PeteB. sorry, maybe I misunderstood the focus of this se. Do you know whether the question would be more appropriate for another se? Maybe diy?

Comment: One way to look at this is that you spent a 150 to find out which roofer to work with.  My experience with contractors is that they get paid for the work they do and not for solving the problem.  Unless you had a contract stating that this roofer would only be paid if he solved the issue, you probably have no legal recourse anyway.

Comment: @JimmyJames: even if the work included something I didn't ask for?

Comment: Sounds like a legal question to me: was the request for further action an implicit request to buy the materials need to effect the repair, or is the contractor still obligated to provide an estimate for what the further materials would cost?

Comment: @anon A lot depends on the laws in your area but in general, it seems reasonable for the contractor who was asked to work on your roof to install something that was missing and relatively inexpensive.  Your story doesn't suggest any sort of nefariousness.  It seems the contractor tried the cheapest thing that might work.  I doubt he knew that it would not resolve the issue.

Comment: " Do you know whether the question would be more appropriate for another se? Maybe diy?" DIY would a strange place to ask a question about hiring someone else to do something.

Comment: What was the agreement with the contractor?

Comment: @JimmyJames: he knew that it wouldn't resolve the issue, he explicitly said beforehand that the missing verge was not related to the leak.

Comment: @Acccumulation: the agreement was to get rid of the leak :)

Comment: First year law students read the [Horse Doctor's Case](https://books.google.com/books?id=lGdFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=horse+doctor%27s+case&source=bl&ots=1E1Zkqxza0&sig=ACfU3U0XWHV2vJqjio-wso1SRac4beHq7g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS2s2GnPDgAhUD9YMKHev9APUQ6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=horse%20doctor's%20case&f=false), which addresses exactly this question. (Caution: don't try to make sense out of this; the case was argued in 1440, and there are many details of the legal system that have long since gone away)

Comment: @PeteBecker: thank you, looks quite relevant. However, I have problems accessing a full version of your link, and google gives me pages not so easy to understand for a layman. Do you have a bottom-line version of the case? :)

Comment: At this point, maybe this post looks more related to law.stackexchange (of which I ignored the existence!). Is there any user with enough reputation willing to do that for me? Thanks

Comment: "he explicitly said beforehand that the missing verge was not related to the leak"  If that's the case you probably have a valid complaint but I agree with the accepted answer.

Comment: @anon -- "not so easy to understand for a layman" -- not so easy to understand for an expert. There are what we would regard today as complex irrelevancies there. "He undertook to cure his horse ... at Oxford"; can he now complain that his horse died at London? The main point is whether the doctor "undertook" (i.e., agreed) to apply his skills or undertook to cure the horse. But: **1440**, not 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's probably not worth your time to fight, especially since he did install the dry verges**

Especially since the work was performed, it's unlikely you'd be successful in fighting this.  The contractor is obviously not going to not charge you for work done, and any court is likely to (initially) side with the contractor.  Unless you want to hire a lawyer (which will cost more than 150gbp), you're better off just letting it go.

Comment: Thank you: I think now I know what I will do. I'll pay him, but before paying I'll send him an e-mail to express my disappointment and warning that I'll give negative feedback on feefo and similar feedback providers.